# Changed The Ellipse Object but The event not emit in fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

[The demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zgr4pmt6/4/)

Replay steps:

1. wait for 3s and `click` the `JSFiddle result`. The ellipse will show.
2. `click` the ellipse object, No console will output.

Questions:

1. Why the Ellipse isn't updating auto when I `setOptions`?
2. How can I correctly listen to the `event`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [setCoords](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#setCoords) after setting `rx,ry` values.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  width: 400,
  height: 400
});
var object = new fabric.Ellipse({
  rx: 0,
  ry: 0,
  fill: 'red',
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
})

object.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  console.log(e)
})
canvas.add(object)
setTimeout(() => {
  object.set({
    rx: 40,
    ry: 60
  }).setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
}, 3000);
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c'></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention. It actually works well.